# Freebase - get Movies AND TV Shows by Artist

Tags: freebase

I am currently doing this:

```
var que = '[{\
  "id": "' + id.id + '",\
  "name": null,\
  "/film/actor/film": [{\
    "film": null,\
    "id": null,\
    "character": null,\
  }]\
}]';
var json = JSON.stringify(eval("(" + que + ")"));
var films = new Array();

    var url2 = 'https://www.googleapis.com/freebase/v1/mqlread?query=' + json;
    $.getJSON(url2,function(data){
        films = data.result[0]["/film/actor/film"];
        for (x=0; x<films.length;x++){
            var title = films[x].film;
            var id = films[x].id;
            $("#movies").text($("#movies").text() + title + ",");   
        }
    })
```

And it works fine so far, but when i check the result, it only includes the Movies an Actor or Actress performed in, how can i include or request all the TV Shows as well?

Comment: exactly why are you building a json string, evaling it, and then re-encoding to even more json?  why not just build that structure DIRECTLY? `var que = [{id:id.id,name:null,"film/actor/flm":[....]}];`?

Answer (score 0):

Include the necessary types and properties for TV Shows and TV Actors, in addition to the film actor properties that you have included now.